# libs3 S3StatusConnectionFailed

Tags: c, amazon-s3

I'm working on doing file uploads using the libs3 library found here: http://libs3.ischo.com/dox/index.html

I'm getting back an error of S3StatusConnectionFailed though. Can someone point me to how this situation could arise? This is my function for uploading files into S3.

```
int putFileIntoS3 (char *fileName, char *s3ObjName) {

S3Status status;
char *key;
struct stat statBuf;
uint64_t fileSize;
FILE *fd;
char *accessKeyId;
char *secretAccessKey;
put_object_callback_data data;

accessKeyId = S3_ACCESS_KEY;
secretAccessKey = S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY;


key = (char*) strchr(s3ObjName, '/');
if (key == NULL) {
    printf("S3 Key not defined!!!!");
    return (-1);
}


*key = '\0';
key++;
if (stat(fileName, &statBuf) == -1) {
    printf("Unknown input file");
    return(-1);
}

fileSize = statBuf.st_size;

fd = fopen(fileName, "r");
if (fd == NULL) {
    printf("Unable to open input file");
    return(-1);
}

data.infile = fd;

S3BucketContext bucketContext =
    {s3ObjName, S3ProtocolHTTP, S3UriStylePath, accessKeyId, secretAccessKey}

S3PutObjectHandler putObjectHandler = {
    { &responsePropertiesCallback, &responseCompleteCallback },
    &putObjectDataCallback
};

if ((status = S3_initialize("s3", S3_INIT_ALL)) != S3StatusOK) {
    printf("Failed to initialize libs3: %s\n",S3_get_status_name(status));
    return(-1);
}

S3_put_object(&bucketContext, key, fileSize, NULL, 0, &putObjectHandler, &data);

if (statusG != S3StatusOK) {
    printf("Put failed: %i\n", statusG);
    S3_deinitialize();
    return(-1);
}

S3_deinitialize();

fclose(fd);
return(0);

}
```

I get back "Put failed: 46", which I'm pretty sure means that it's an S3StatusConnectionFailed error.

Any help would be great, or even pointers to a boto-like library that I can use instead of the drudgery that is doing this in C++.

Thanks!

Comment: This is actually C, not C++ :)

Comment: I'm saving it in upload.cpp and I'm using g++ as my compiler...I was under the impression that this would still work.

Comment: yes, calling it from C++ works cuz libs3.h is asking g++ not to mangle names(extern "C" construct in libs3.h), so it's totally fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i tried putting non-null value but i was getting same error. i found out the reason for this : you must set the contentLength of "data" (of type put_object_callback_data) as below

```
fileSize = statBuf.st_size;
//viren+
data.contentLength = fileSize;
//viren-
//..
data.infile = fd;
```

Oh, and also make sure you have correct permissions set on your bucket.

Answer (score 0):

use NULL for first param in S3_initialize. S3StatusConnectionFailed is indicative that "s3" url maybe wrong. i assume you are providing correct S3_ACCESS_KEY and S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY.